# Get 1st occurrence combined to 3 columns

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a table `Table` like this:

```
ColumnA (VARCHAR)|ColumnB (VARCHAR)|ColumnC (VARCHAR)|ColumnD (DATE)
     A1                 B1               C1          2012-12-06
     A1                 B1               C1          2012-12-12
     A2                 B2               C2          2012-12-07
     A2                 B2               C2          2012-12-09
```

I want to select only the 1st occurrence combined to ColumnA-ColumnB-ColumnC so the result will be something like this:

```
A1 | B1 | C1 | 2012-12-06
A2 | B2 | C2 | 2012-12-07
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an aggregate function on the Date column and the group by the rest:

```
select ColumnA, ColumnB, ColumnC, Min(ColumnD)
from yourtable
group by ColumnA, ColumnB, ColumnC
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/4d233/1)

Or you can use `row_number()`:

```
select ColumnA, ColumnB, ColumnC, ColumnD
from
(
  select ColumnA, ColumnB, ColumnC, ColumnD,
    row_number() over(partition by ColumnA, ColumnB, ColumnC order by ColumnD) rn
  from yourtable
) src
where rn = 1
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/4d233/6)

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a group-by is what you're going for.

```
SELECT ColumnA, ColumnB, ColumnC, MIN(ColumnD)
FROM MyTable
GROUP BY ColumnA, ColumnB, ColumnC
```